# SpringSecurity RememberMeServices is not injected via annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-security

I am trying to configure SpringSecurity to work with Remember Me authentication.

Here is my Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    DatabasePersistentTokeRepositoryImpl databasePersistentTokeRepositoryImpl;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
        http
        .authenticationProvider(rememberMeAuthenticationProvider())
        .rememberMe().tokenRepository(databasePersistentTokeRepositoryImpl).tokenValiditySeconds((int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(7, TimeUnit.DAYS))
        .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean()
    public AuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new RememberMeAuthenticationProvider("KEY");
    }

    @Bean()
    public TokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
        TokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("KEY", userDetailsService);
        rememberMeServices.setAlwaysRemember(true);
        return rememberMeServices;
    }
}
```

I see that rememberMeServices is not injected in RememberMeConfigurer. And that results in creating RememberMeAuthenticationFilter which refers to wrong rememberMeServices.

There is a section in Spring Security documentation describing this process using XML.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#session-mgmt

What is wrong with my injection and is it possible do to this without XML after all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't injecting it. There is no autowiring for the `RememberMeConfigurer`. Also why are you configuring so many beans?

The `RememberMeAuthenticationProvider` is already created for you, if you want to use a different key specify it using `key("KEY")`. This in turn will be used to create the `RememberMeServices`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    DatabasePersistentTokeRepositoryImpl databasePersistentTokeRepositoryImpl;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
        http
        .rememberMe()
            .key("KEY")
            .tokenRepository(databasePersistentTokeRepositoryImpl)
                .tokenValiditySeconds((int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(7, TimeUnit.DAYS))
        .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

If you really need to set the `alwaysRemember` property to true you could use an `ObjectPostProcessor` to post process the filter and configure the `RememberMeServices` from there.

You would also have injected the wrong type of `RememberMeServices` as the one configured doesn't use the `PersistentTokeRepository`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an example of the code that @m-deinum's suggestion of an `ObjectPostProcessor` that sets alwaysRemember to true would look like would look like:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
    http
    .rememberMe()
        .key("KEY")
        .tokenRepository(databasePersistentTokeRepositoryImpl)
        .tokenValiditySeconds((int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(7, TimeUnit.DAYS))
        .withObjectPostProcessor( new ObjectPostProcessor<RememberMeAuthenticationFilter>() {

            @Override
            public <O extends RememberMeAuthenticationFilter> O postProcess( O object) {

                RememberMeAuthenticationFilter rmaf = (RememberMeAuthenticationFilter)
                PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices rms = (PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices)rmaf.getRememberMeServices();
                rms.setAlwaysRemember( true );

                return object;
            }                           
        })
    .and()
        .csrf().disable();
}
```